# PHP flip 32bit integer

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

get 32 bit unsigned integer. Flip all the bits (0->1 and 1->0 ) and return the result as an unsigned integer.

Take 1 for example, as unsigned 32-bits is 00000000000000000000000000000001 and doing the flipping we get 11111111111111111111111111111110 which in turn is 4294967294.

I can turn decimal number to binary , but it does not contain 32 bits to flip.
Please help me with this.

Comment: Lets say $d=10;   I want to convert to 32bit binary and flip (0->1 and 1-> 0). then I need decimal value of that. from php.

Comment: Maybe `echo sprintf('%032b', 4294967294);` is a starting point for you

Comment: I want to do this in PHP.

Comment: user3783243, yes your suggestion to use sprintf (for string handling to add leading zeros) is clearly stated as an example in the PHP official documentation for [decbin](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did it thanx everyone. This is how I did.

```
$function flippingBits($n) { 
    $binary = sprintf('%032b', $n);
    $fliped = strtr($binary, [1,0]);
    return bindec($fliped);
}
```

Comment: excellent ! happy coding bro

Answer (score 0):

For PHP, you may use decbin and bindec for decimal to binary and binary to decimal respectively, and use a simple function to invert the bits.

I have made a function xinvert to do the job, as follows:

```
<?php
$value1=10;
echo xinvert($value1) ."<br>";

function xinvert($value1){
$string1= sprintf( "%032d",decbin($value1));
$index=0;
$string2="";
  while ($index < strlen($string1) ) {
   if (substr($string1, $index,1)=="0"){
     $string2.="1";
       }else{
     $string2.="0";
    }
   $index++;
   }
return bindec($string2);
}
?>
```

Note: I have used sprintf( "%032d",decbin($value1)); to **make it 32 bit** in length, which is inspired by user3783243

Answer (score 0):

This is very much a basics of programming issue; and anyone that posts code that is using string handling is very much not someone you want to learn from.

That said, pack() is an excellent function; but doesn't help with understanding exactly what is happening.

To invert a 32 bit value; let's think about an int in PHP.  First off int's are 64 bits; but that's okay; we can use masks as well, to ensure we get the expected answer (even if PHP changes the default int width).

```
$value = some_int_value; // the value to invert
$value = !$value; // flip all 64 bits
$value = $value & 0xffffffff; // ignore anything but the last 32 bits
```

Or more succinctly

```
$invert_32_unsigned = 0xffffffff & !intval($value);
```

Comment: 2 beers to this gentlemen

Comment: another option is `$result = ~$number & 0xffffffff`

Comment: Absolutely, but that doesn't have the nice three step expansion; but that's the way I'd write it in production.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a single binary operation: the XOR

```
echo $v ^ 0xffffffff;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is basics of programming, PHP has a full support of bitwise operators, including bitwise NOT:

`$result = unpack('V', ~pack('V', 1234))`

Pack and unpack are used here to deal with a fact that all integers in PHP are signed 64 bits integers. Don't listen to people that are converting 4-byte numbers into strings or array of strings, they have no clue what they do.